# Staying safe and secure

Tags: riddle, word

I am a nine letter word. No matter how hard you try, it is impossible to pass through. Part of me is useful to end an argument or a fight. Another part of me, in the wrong hands, can be catastrophic. You see part of me everywhere. Part of me read backwards describes criminals or crowds. Who am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it

> Bombproof?

The word implies indestructible. Cannot pass through

End an argument

> Give Proof

Wrong hands catastrophic

> Bomb

See part of me everywhere

> roof

Reverse is criminals or crowd

> Mob